# The length of the smallest co-prime chain between any two integers

Tags: number-theory

Consider the following statement:

> for any $a < b \in \mathbb{N}$, one of the following holds:
>
> 1. $\gcd(a,b) = 1$.
> 2. there is a $a < x < b$ such that
>    $\gcd(a,x) = \gcd(x,b) = 1$.
> 3. there are $a < x < y < b$ such that
>    $\gcd(a,x) = \gcd(x,y) = \gcd(y,b) = 1$.

Is this statement true?

---

#### Motivation:

I found a variant of this problem in one of the recent algorithms competitions.

Consider the following problem:

**Input:** two integers $a$ and $b$ where $a \lt b$.

**Output:** smallest number $l$ such that there are integers
$a = x_0 < x_1 < x_2 < \ldots < x_l < x_{l+1} = b$ such that
all consecutive integers in the list are co-prime:
$\gcd(x_i, x_{i+1}) = 1$ for $i=0,\ldots, l$.

Examples:

1. $a = 7, b = 13$:
   $\gcd(a,b) = 1$, therefore $l = 0$.
2. $a = 10, b = 12$:
   $\gcd(a,b) = 2 \neq 1$, therefore $l \geq 1$.
   Let the sequence be $10, 11, 12$. $\gcd(10, 11) = 1, \gcd(11, 12) = 1$.
3. $a = 2184, b = 2200$:
   There is no $a< x < b$ such that $\gcd(a,x)=\gcd(x,b)=1$.
   However, we can find $2$ integers that satisfy this problem.

There is a reference algorithm that algorithms are evaluated against.
That algorithm assumes that

1. There is always an $l$ that satisfies the condition.
2. $l\leq 2$.

I don't see why they are true.

I have a polynomial time algorithm that does not assume either of them.
I am not losing out on the asymptotic performance
compared to the reference algorithm,
but I could get the performance constants much lower
if I can understand and prove the validity of the assumptions.

Comment: That it is always solvable can be seen by considering all integers between $A$ and $B$ ( $N_1=A+1$, $N_2=A+2$,..). This shows $L \leq B-A-1$.

Comment: polkjh: that seems to work, given that GCD( n, n+1 ) = 1 (which is true).

Comment: Please use the latex support available on this site.

Comment: Perhaps this is better suited to math.se.

Comment: Related: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Erd%C5%91s%E2%80%93Woods_number

Comment: I think you may have more luck on [math.se].

Answer (score 1):

The conjecture $\ell \leq 2$ seems to be open. It is stated as Conjecture 3 in [a paper of Dowe](http://journals.cambridge.org/download.php?file=%2FJAZ%2FJAZ1_47_01%2FS1446788700031220a.pdf). Dowe does show that the Goldbach conjecture implies that $\ell \leq 3$, and mentions that Alan Woods showed in his PhD thesis that $\ell$ is bounded. Perhaps the recent proof of the odd Goldbach conjecture also implies a definite and small bound.

If $\ell > 1$ then $b-a$ is an Erdős-Woods number. In particular, if $\ell > 2$ then both $b-a$ and $b-a-1$ have to be Erdős-Woods numbers. [A059756](https://oeis.org/A059756) lists the first few Erdős-Woods numbers. While all numbers on that list are even, there are also odd Erdős-Woods numbers, some of which are listed in [A111042](https://oeis.org/A111042). The smallest values of $a$ corresponding to given differences are listed in [A059757](https://oeis.org/A059757). While this list is not increasing, it does seem as if the numbers are growing pretty fast. Any counterexample to $\ell \leq 2$ would to be such that both $b-a$ and $b-a-1$ are Erdős-Woods numbers, and in particular $b-a > 430$ (per A059756). This suggests (but does not prove) that any such counterexample will be huge, and so for all practical purposes we can assume that $\ell \leq 2$.